# Why won't Vercel run my JavaScript code linked in HTML

Tags: javascript, deployment, vercel

I've not had this problem before but now it seems I can't run my JavaScript code on my Vercel deployment. It just doesn't detect it, or so it seems. I can't for the life of my figure it out. https://typing-speed-test-phi.vercel.app/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The url for your script 404s https://typing-speed-test-phi.vercel.app/script.min.js

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Can you share your code so that someone can help you?

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/ProcrastinatingEntrepreneur/typing-speed-test
I think I solved it by moving the script into a new directory called /src/ and updating the link in the HTML file. Never had to do this on other Vercel projects so I'm still thinking I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using a source file named `script.js` and then attempting to load a file named `script.min.js`, which did not exist.

Looks like you solved your issue in [e696b1b6](https://github.com/ProcrastinatingEntrepreneur/typing-speed-test/commit/e696b1b6ec4ae07817a45e0be1c78401c0eb632c) by using the same name in both places.